# HighCharts specific chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Is there an ability to build the following chart with HighCharts library?

Comment: You can use gauge chart http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, [the donut chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut)

you can get rid of the extra data inside the donut and you will get what you need

check this http://jsfiddle.net/wtQ87/

{

```
                color: colors[0],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'MSIE versions',
                    categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                    data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
                    color: colors[0]
                }
```

Comment: My main concerns are: 1) thumbnails inside each of serie 2) specific shape of chart (it is not a round like in pie chart)

Comment: note sure about the thumbnails, but the "not rounded" you can add a 30% white serie to get the effect of half round donut

Comment: thank you - this is not exactly what I need, but the closest solution to it.